# Populating ComboBox and CheckedListBox from Database, C#

Tags: c#

Ok, as the title says, I'm trying to populate a combobox from a database, then change the contents of the checkedlistbox based on the change in the combobox. The problem here is, I'm about as lost as I could be. I decided to go with an access database (db1.mdb, in the same dir as the exe). The primary data table Table1 has the names of the items that should go in the combobox (item1, item2, item3). Then, I have separate tables for each value(tableitem1, tableitem2, tableitem3), and the listbox will be using these one at a time, listing the "Item Name" fields, of which there are varying amounts in each table. After checking off the options in the checkedlistbox, I need to grab the values from the other columns in that table "value1 and value2" from the database table associated with the checked list box. I've been programming for about 5 years, but have never needed to manipulate a database before, so I'm totally lost.

Comment: Can you be little more clear? Based on my understanding so far you want to fetch data in Combobox and when someone selects something, you want to fetch someother values and show as checkboxlist.. Do you know how to create a DataSet and bind it to the controls?? If No - I would suggest start with the basics first... do some simple stuff and then you can try out yourself.

Comment: If you've been programming for 5 years you should know how to populate a combobox and so on - maybe you should post a question that just addresses the data access part? This question won't get a good answer because it's too broad.

Comment: I'll clarify... All database values are text values. The dataset is where I'm getting confused, I can load the combobox easy enough using some info I gained here earlier, but then fetching the new data table from the name in the combobox is giving me a migraine. I've programmed for 5+ years in forms of basic, I'm pretty new to c#, and I've only done recreational programming in the past so I've never needed to form a database and load from it. I tried making the OP as informative as I could with value names and all, and apparently lost clarity. Sajoshi seems to have my general intent though.

Comment: Here is an example for reading data into a dataset - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx.  ConnectionString should be something like "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source=c:/path/MyDB.mdb".

Answer (score 0):

I found some good code and advice reading around more threads here. Apparently my main problem was with spacing in the table names, so I removed the spaces in the tables and the code. This code works to load the proper values in both the combobox and the checkedlistbox. Now, I just need to load the values from the rows corresponding to the checked list and load the values from 2 different columns into 2 different string arrays. This is my very first time ever working with a database, so I was just getting lost in how the system was interpreting what I wrote.

```
    private OleDbConnection myConn;
    private OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter;
    private DataViewManager dviewmanager;
    private DataSet dset;

    private OleDbConnection myConn2;
    private OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter2;
    private DataViewManager dviewmanager2;
    private DataSet dset2;

    private void cmbDatabaseFill()
    {
        string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=DB1.mdb";
        try
        {
            myConn = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
            myConn.Open();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in connection ..." + ex.Message);
        }

        string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM Index;";

        dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConn);

        dset = new DataSet();

        dAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Index");

        dAdapter.Fill(dset);

        this.dviewmanager = dset.DefaultViewManager;

        this.cmbMain.DataSource = this.dviewmanager;

        this.cmbMain.DisplayMember = "Index.List";

        this.myConn.Close();
    }

    private void cmbMain_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clbDatabaseFill();
    }

    private void clbDatabaseFill()
    {
        string newTableName = cmbMain.Text.Replace(" ", "");

        string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=DB1.mdb";
        try
        {
            myConn2 = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
            myConn2.Open();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in connection ..." + ex.Message);
        }

        string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM " + newTableName + ";";

        dAdapter2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConn2);

        dset2 = new DataSet();

        dAdapter2.TableMappings.Add("Table", newTableName);

        try
        {
            dAdapter2.Fill(dset2);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.dviewmanager2 = dset2.DefaultViewManager;

        this.clbOpt.DataSource = this.dviewmanager2;

        this.clbOpt.DisplayMember = newTableName + ".ValName";

        this.myConn2.Close();
    }
```